# Two 'and's in a title

Tags: adjectives, ambiguity, coordinating-conjunctions

I have written a paper which I have titled in the format *Adjective1 and Adjective2 Noun1 and Noun2*. Both adjectives modify only Noun1. The two nouns are inherently not related and the point of the paper is to show the relation of Noun1 with Noun2, but Noun1 needs to be mentioned first because it is given more focus. An example of a phrase in this format would be *Blue and Red Apples and Planets*. Or *Short and Tall Buildings and Cats*.

Is this kind of phrasing grammatically incorrect, unnatural or confusing? How can it be rephrased?

I can probably rephrase it into *Blue and Red Apples and their connections to Planets*, but using the phrase "and their connection" is rare in my field since papers whose titles are lists are already implied to be about the items on the lists and their connection with each other. It is not uncommon, for example, for papers to have a title like *Apples, Buildings and Cats*.

Comment: If it's just about titles, you could _italicize_ to show emphasis— _Short and tall buildings_ and _cats_.

Comment: By default I would take the adjectives as applying to both nouns.  The simplest way of breaking that association, I think, would be a comma: *Blue and Red Dogs, And Cats*.

Comment: The alternative to a comma is to rearrange e.g. "Planets and Blue and Red Apples". If the adjectives can't be applied to the second noun, or only in a very unnatural way, e.g. "Fierce and docile cats and collars", then you could probably keep it as it is.